# Some issues with Timed Notifications (Android)?

Tags: android, notifications, broadcastreceiver, alarm, android-alarms

I am trying to create an automatic notification at say 9:00 AM.

I created the following codes but I'm unable to get an Automatic Notification.

And, I did add the required permissions in the Android Manifest File.

In the `MainActivity.class`' `onCreate` method I called the function :
`setAlarm();`

```
public void setAlarm() {

  AlarmManager alarmMgr;
  PendingIntent alarmIntent;

  alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
  Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Notifications.class);
  alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 1001, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

  Calendar calendar_now = Calendar.getInstance();
  Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
  calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
  calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 9);
  calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);

  alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 1000 * 60 * 1, alarmIntent);

  if(calendar_now.getTimeInMillis() == calendar.getTimeInMillis()) {
    new Notifications().createNotification(getApplicationContext(), getIntent(), "Stock-Market Alert", "The Market opens shortly.");
  }

}
```

The Notifications.class is as follows :

```
public class Notifications extends BroadcastReceiver {

  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String notificationTitle = "Default Title", notificationMessage = "Default Message";

    createNotification(context, intent, notificationTitle, notificationMessage );
  }

  public void createNotification(Context context, Intent intent, String notificationTitle, String notificationMessage) {

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 1001, 
               new Intent(context, Repeating_activity.class), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
          .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.arrow_up_float)
          .setContentTitle(notificationTitle)
          .setContentText(notificationMessage)
          .setTicker("Alert Message !")
          .setAutoCancel(true)
          .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.stat_sys_warning);

    builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    builder.setDefaults(NotificationCompat.DEFAULT_VIBRATE);
    builder.setDefaults(NotificationCompat.DEFAULT_SOUND);

    notificationManager.notify(1001, builder.build());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you're trying to compare milliseconds, rarely you're going to match the same millisecond (to don't say almost never). Also, add you logic to compare time on the Receiver. Try the following code:

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    int currentHour = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR);
    int currentMinute = cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    if (currentHour == 9 && currentMinute == 00) {
        String notificationTitle = "Default Title", notificationMessage = "Default Message";
        createNotification(context, intent, notificationTitle, notificationMessage );
    }
}
```

And your setAlarm() method can be simple like this:

```
    public void setAlarm(){
         AlarmManager alarmMgr;
         PendingIntent alarmIntent;

        alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Notifications.class);
        alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 1001, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 1000 * 60 * 1, alarmIntent);

    }
```

Comment: Sorry still nothing. When I remove the time constraint and use an onClick(), Notification appears but nothing with either of our code above :(

Comment: Is your BroadcastReceiver declared on AndroidManifest.xml? Try to send an Intent on your onClick() to double check if the problem is the AlarmManager or the Receiver.

Comment: No problem there. on OnClick, the notification works

Comment: could you share the code that is working on your onClick method?

Comment: Just call the setAlarm() in a button onClick method. It works(my original code)

Comment: When you say it works, you mean the notification ("Stock-Market Alert") or the BroadcastReceiver starts to be hit every 1 minute?

Comment: Only the notification. It doesn't repeat after every minute although.

Comment: Try adding only the intent and the Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Notifications.class);sendBroadcast(intent) inside your onClick method, it should show a notification.